# Equivalence of angular momenta eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, eigenvalue

Consider two angular momentum operators $\hat{J}_{1}$ and $\hat{J}_{2}$ and operator $J := J_{1} \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes J_{2}$ where respectively we have common eigenstates $|j_1j_2;m_1 m_2 \rangle$ of $\hat{J}_{1}$ and $\hat{J}_{2}$ and $|j_1,j_2; jm \rangle$ a common eigenstate of $\hat{J}^2$ and $\hat{J}_{z}$.

Consider an example where we have a single spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particle with say $j_{1} = l$, $m_{1} = m_{l}$, $j_{2} = s = \frac{1}{2}$ and $m_{2} = m_{s} =  \pm\frac{1}{2}$. Consider now the angular-momentum configuration in which $m_{l}$ and $m_{s}$ are both maximal-that is, $l$ and $\frac{1}{2}$, respectively. The total $m = m_{l} + m_{s}$ is $l + \frac{1}{2}$, which is possible only for $j = l + \frac{1}{2}$ and not for $j = l - \frac{1}{2}$. Why does it followws that $|j_{1}j_{2}; m_{l}= l, m_{s} = \frac{1}{2} \rangle$ must be equal to $|j_1j_2;j=l+\frac{1}{2}, m = l + \frac{1}{2} \rangle$ up to phase factor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ingredients needed.

1. For a given set of states with angular momentum $j$, only the state with $m=j$ is killed by $\hat L_+$.  This follows from the usual
   \begin{align}
   \hat L_+\vert \ell,m\rangle &=\sqrt{(\ell-m)(\ell+m+1)}\vert \ell,m+1
   \rangle\, ,\\
   \hat L_+\vert \ell,\ell\rangle&=0\, .
   \end{align}
2. State counting: in your full Hilbert space spanned by states of the form $\vert j_1m_1\rangle \vert j_2m_2\rangle$, there is only one state with eigenvalue $m=\frac{1}{2}+\ell$, and it is the state
   $$
   \vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle = \vert \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\rangle\vert \ell,\ell\rangle\, .
   \tag{1}
   $$
   *All* other states of the form $\vert s,m_s\rangle\vert \ell,m_\ell\rangle$ have a lower eigenvalue $m_s+m_\ell$ of $\hat L_x$ since by assumption $m_s+m_\ell<\ell+\textstyle\frac{1}{2}$.

Using
$\hat L_+=\hat L_{+,1}\otimes 1+1\otimes \hat L_{+,2}$
one easily verifies that
\begin{align}
\hat L_+\vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle &= \left[\hat L_{+,1}\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle\right]\vert \ell,\ell\rangle+\vert \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle\left[\hat L_{+,2}\vert \ell,\ell\rangle\right]=0
\end{align}
so that $\vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle $ *must be* a state with $m=j$.  Since this $m$ is $\ell+\textstyle\frac{1}{2}$, it follows that $j=\ell+\textstyle\frac{1}{2}$.  Of course, we could also include an arbitrary phase on the right hand side of (1) and the result would be the same.

To see how the argument *does not* work for other states, 
consider the states with $m=\ell-1/2$.  Indeed there are two such states:
\begin{align}
\vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell-1\rangle\, ,\qquad 
\vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=-\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle
\end{align}

The state $\vert j=\ell-\textstyle{\frac{1}{2}},m_j=\ell-\textstyle{\frac{1}{2}}\rangle$ must be a linear combination of these two.  To see note that the action of $\hat L_+$ on $\vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell-1\rangle$ *or* the $\vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=-\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle$ is not enough to kill the states individually.  However, one easily verifies that 
\begin{align}
&\hat L_+
\left(\alpha \vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=-\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle+\beta 
\vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=-\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle
\right)\\
&= \alpha \vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle+\beta \sqrt{2\ell}\vert s=\textstyle\frac{1}{2},\ell;m_s=\frac{1}{2},m_\ell=\ell\rangle=0
\end{align}
provided $\alpha+\sqrt{2\ell}\beta=0$.

---

Edit: in answer to a follow up question on rotation matrices.

A rotation of the type
$$
e^{-i\beta L_y}=e^{i\beta L_{y,1}}\otimes e^{i\beta L_{y,2}}
$$
since the action of $L_{y,1}$ commutes with the action of $L_{y,2}$.  (The same observation holds for all rotations in the different spaces, i.e. $[\hat L_{k,1},\hat L_{i,2}]=0$.)

Thus, as the basis $\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle$ is ``uncoupled" in the sense that 
$$
\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle=\vert j_1m_1\rangle\otimes \vert j_2m_2\rangle
$$
it follows that
\begin{align}
\langle j_1j_2;m_1'm_2'\vert e^{-i\beta L_y}\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle
&=\langle j_1m_1'\vert e^{-i\beta L_{y,1}} \vert j_1m_1\rangle 
\langle j_2m_2'\vert e^{-i\beta L_{y,2}} \vert j_2m_2\rangle\, ,\\
&=D^{j_1}_{m_1'm_1}(0,\beta,0) D^{j_2}_{m_2'm_2}(0,\beta,0)
\end{align}
and more generally
$$
\langle j_1j_2;m_1'm_2'\vert R\vert j_1j_2;m_1m_2\rangle
=D^{j_1}_{m_1'm_1}(R) D^{j_2}_{m_2'm_2}(R)
$$

Comment: Thanks for this substantial answer. Just one thing that I'm not sure of is your reasoning for the section "how the argument *does not* work for other states". As I understand, your reasoning is that since $\hat{L}_{+}$ does not kill either $|s = \frac{1}{2}, l; m_{s} = \frac{1}{2}, m_{l} = l - 1\rangle$ or $|s = \frac{1}{2}, l; m_{s} = -\frac{1}{2}, m_{l} = l\rangle$ it follows that $|j= l-1, m_{j} = l-1 \rangle$ must be a linear combintation of these two and hence not equivalent to either one.

Comment: This doesn't agree with Sakurai's "Modern Quantum Mechanics" which says that eigenstates of form $|j,m_{j} \rangle$ can only be written as linear combintation of eigenstates of the form $|s, l; m_s, m_{l} \rangle$ given that $m_{j} = m_{s} + m_{l}$. I confirmed this in a comment of [my other post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/333097/addition-of-angular-momenta-and-clebsch-coefficients/333213?noredirect=1#comment746980_333213). In your case $m_{j} = l-1$ while $m_{s} + m_{j} = l -\frac{1}{2}$, thus your $|j,m_{j}\rangle$ can't be the stated linear combintation. What do you think?

Comment: You are right: it was a typo on my part.  The values of $j$ go in steps of $1$: the largest is $\ell+1/2$, the next largest is $\ell-1/2$.  I have corrected "The state 
$\vert j=\ell-1,m_j=\ell-1\rangle$" to  "The state  $\vert j=\ell-\textstyle\frac{1}{2},m_j=\ell-\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\rangle$".

Comment: Okay great thanks I understand now. Do you maybe know why when we consider the respective basis kets $|j_1j_2;m_{1}m_{2} \rangle$ and $|j,m \rangle$ with a rotation operator $\mathcal{D}(R)$ we get the equation $$\langle j_1 j_2; m_1 m_2| \mathcal{D}(R)| j_{1}j_{2}; m'_{1}m'_{2} \rangle = \langle j_{1}m_{2}| \mathcal{D}(R)| j_{1}m'_{1} \rangle \langle j_{2}m_{2}| \mathcal{D}(R)|j_{2} m'_{2} \rangle?$$

Comment: @JohnDoe updated my answer.

Comment: Could I ask one thing. To prove that the direction eigenket $|\hat{z} \rangle$ is an eigenket of $\hat{L}_{z}$, is it sufficient to note that $| \hat{z} \rangle$ is invariant under rortation around the $z$-axis and then note that $$e^{i \theta L_z}| \hat{z} \rangle = 
 |\hat{z} \rangle \implies \frac{d}{d \theta}[e^{i \theta L_z}| \hat{z} \rangle] = (\frac{d }{d \theta}e^{i \theta L_z} )| \hat{z} \rangle + e^{i \theta L_z} \frac{d | \hat{z} \rangle}{d \theta}  = i L_z e^{i \theta L_z}| \hat{z} \rangle = iL_z| \hat{z} \rangle = 0 \implies L_z| \hat{z} \rangle = 0$$